# How to find all cell arrays in a cell array, where the row count is bigger than a threshold?

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array

I have an array of cells `B`. Each element of `B` has a different rows number. How can I access only elements of `B` with **number of rows grater than threshold**?

I tried:

```
A = B{cellfun('length', B) >= threshold};
```

Can this be done without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
B(cellfun('length', B) >= threshold )
```

or

```
B(cellfun(@(x) numel(x) >= threshold, B))
```

should work.

Both of them counts the elements in the inner cell arrays.

---

If you really want to have just the cells, **where the row count** is bigger or equal to the threshold:

```
B(cellfun('size', B, 1) >= threshold )
```

or

```
B(cellfun(@(x) size(x, 1) >= threshold, B))
```

**Example**

```
arr_Row1Col1 = {1};
arr_Row1Col2 = {1,2};
arr_Row2Col1 = {1;2};
arr_Row2Col2 = {1,2;3,4};

threshold = 2;

B = {arr_Row1Col1, arr_Row1Col2, arr_Row2Col1, arr_Row2Col2};

% All inner-cells that have more than one element
B(cellfun('length', B) >= threshold )

% All inner-cells that have more than one row
B(cellfun('size', B, 1) >= threshold )
```

*Outputs:*

```
ans = {1x2 cell}    {2x1 cell}    {2x2 cell}
ans = {2x1 cell}    {2x2 cell}
```